# Detect script defer support without testing

Tags: javascript

Is there a reliable way of detecting if a browser supports the `<script>` attribute "defer" without testing? I'm not interested in creating multiple script blocks both defered and not and seeing which executes first. I'm looking for legitimate feature detection. `"defer" in document.createElement("script")` returns `true` just about everywhere, giving a lot of false positives.

Comment: `'defer' in document.createElement('script')` returns `true` in browsers that don't support it? Really?

Comment: Yes. Try in the address bars of Firefox 3, Opera 10, Safari, or Chrome, `javascript:alert('defer' in document.createElement('script'));` Returns true for every single one. Same problem with `writingMode in document.body.style`. Very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Paul Irish's [comprehensive research and article on script @defer](https://github.com/paulirish/lazyweb-requests/issues/42) document in his lazyweb-requests repository, I don't think `defer` behaves reliably enough to use even if you could feature detect it.